# Obtaining distance matrix from MatchIt package

Tags: r

Is it possible to obtain the distance matrix when using the MatchIt package with a Mahalanobis distance?

```
library("MatchIt")
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ re74 + re75 + educ + black + hispan + age, data = lalonde, distance="mahalanobis",method = "nearest")

# this contains only NAs
m.out$distance
```

Comment: Should a "MatchIt" tag be added?

Comment: See if it helps - https://lists.gking.harvard.edu/pipermail/matchit/2011-January/000174.html

Comment: You can use `str(m.out)` to see the elements that are returned after the the match. This may help you to figure out what to pull out. Note that the `matchit` package is, for a the most part, a wrapper for a bunch of other matching packages such as `Matching` and `optmatch`. I use these packages, but haven't used `matchit`.